# Why pagination is not working with tax_query param?

Tags: wp-query, query, pagination, tax-query, advanced-taxonomy-queries

this is my query:

```
  $p_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => $post_type
    ,'post_status' => 'publish'
    ,'posts_per_page' => $per_page // 6
    ,'paged' => $page // 2
    ,'post__not_in' => array($first_post) // an ID
    ,'tax_query' => array(
       array(
         'taxonomy' => $data['tax'] // tax slug
         ,'field'    => 'slug'
         ,'terms' => $data['term'] // term slug
       )
    )
  ));
```

Pagination works properly without the tax_query. As soon as I add it, on page 2 something strange happens:

- it returns the correct number of items (the remaining number of items)
- the items are wrong: they are the initial ones again.

In other words, if the items `per_page` are 6, and the total are 8, on page 2 I'll get 2 items, but instead of being items 7,8, they'll be 1,2.

Why? What's wrong?

Comment: Nothing here looks wrong to me. Is `$first_post` still being set correctly? Are you inspecting `$p_query` to see this happen or is this based on your template code?

Comment: all the params are correct, I checked all. That's my own code.

Comment: Everything looks correct to me. Check to make sure you're not resetting the query early or having parameters overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution by myself. In brief: use `'order' => 'DESC'`

---

The long story:

Since I was doing the first page query via php (standard loop), and instead, the above is done via ajax, passing pagination (thus page 1 is php, the following are ajax), there was a mismatch about the order.
I was still retrieving what is seemed to be page 1 posts because the query was done with the default `ASC` order, while the standard loop works with DESC order by default (date-based). So the posts retrived by ajax were in fact of page 2!

By inverting the order, I now get the right posts.